# Displaying component in a differente page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My react app consists two main pages, the first page contains 4 main sections that displays together (Home - about - products - contact) and I navigate between them by smooth scrolling.

What I expect is when I click on the image of a specific product it needs to open the product specs page in a new page. But it opens it in the same page and the component is added below the contact section.

Here is the code :

```
import React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter , Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Home from './components/Home'
import About from './components/About'
import Machines from './components/Machines'
import Contact from './components/Contact'
import Product1 from './components/Product1'


function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar />
      <Home />
      <About />
      <Machines />
      <Contact />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/product1" element={<Product1 />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
//Machines.js
<figure>
  <Link to="/product1"><img src={image1} alt="Image 1" /></Link>
  <figcaption>
    <p>Manual Cocker Machine</p>
   </figcaption>
 </figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are ***unconditionally*** rendering all your main content, e.g. `Home`, `About`, etc, ***and then*** below that ***conditionally*** rendering the `Product1` component via the router and its own route.

If you only want the main content to be conditionally rendered when on a "home" page then you'll want to ***conditionally*** render them on a route as well.

Here's an example refactor to use a layout route to render the `Navbar` component and each page as a nested route under it. The `Navbar` will render above all routed content on each page, your main content will be rendered on the root `"/"` path, and the product page will still be rendered on `"/product1"` as before.

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Outlet
} from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Home from './components/Home'
import About from './components/About'
import Machines from './components/Machines'
import Contact from './components/Contact'
import Product1 from './components/Product1'

const AppLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<AppLayout />}>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={(
              <>
                <Home />
                <About />
                <Machines />
                <Contact />
              </>
            )}
          />
          <Route path="/product1" element={<Product1 />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function App() {

return (
  <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' index element={<Home />}></Route>
          <Route path='/home' element={<Home />}></Route>
          <Route path='/about' element={<About />}></Route>
          <Route path='/machines' element={<Machines />}></Route>
          <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />}></Route>
          <Route path='/product1' element={<Product1 />} ></Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
)}
```

The navbar component should be rendered in each page, not here at the top level

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still doesn't work, the home, about, machines, contact components are sections in the main home page not in different pages, so they share the same path, I want them to be displayed together then when i click on the product it routes to the /product1 path and open in its own page